# AngularJS ngRoute conflicts with CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations

[link to: actual problem](https://grinjo.nl/arthur/AngularJS/)

ngRoute updates the url. When clicking the main menu on top of the page, the layout jumps to the new state without the transition effect because of this url update. However when I open an activity from the menu on the left the google maps initialization is included and everything seems to work fine. (Mac Chrome only tested for now).

Inside $routeProvider no difference between both routes:

```js
.when('/c/:id', {
 controller: 'ContentController',
 templateUrl: 'js/views/content.html',
 resolve: {
  redirect: function ($route) { $route.current.params.redirect = 'c'; }
 }
})
.when('/a/:id', {
 controller: 'SearchController',
 templateUrl: 'js/views/activity.html',
 resolve: {
  redirect: function ($route) { $route.current.params.redirect = 'a'; }
 }
})
```

Inside ContentController (which doesn't work well):

```js
app.controller('ContentController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, content) {
 let redirect = $routeParams.redirect;
 
 content.success(function(data) {
  $scope.content = data;
  if (redirect==='c' && $routeParams.id) {
   $scope.content_detail = data[$routeParams.id];
  }
 });
});
```

Inside SearchController (which works because of the google maps initialization):

```js
app.controller('SearchController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $filter, APIsearch) {
 let redirect = $routeParams.redirect;
  
 //load results
 APIsearch.success(function(data) {
  $scope.results = data;
  
  if (redirect==='a' && $routeParams.id) {
   $scope.result_detail = $filter('getSelected')(data, $routeParams.id);
   
   initialize($scope.result_detail.polyline);
  };
 });
});
```

What does google.maps do which makes this work?!

Comment: It is not only google maps and activity, if you click on any of main sections, De Clup, routes... and close them transitions come back. The problem lies in your HTML directives or css not in JS, as I'm seeing you're not using animations in any of the controllers, you need to share those.

Comment: @Babak You mean I need to use ng-animate ? Because I thought this was not necessary for my website.. And when closing them is actually true, but in that case the url isn't updated.

Comment: ngAnimate makes lots of things easier for you as it hooks every transition to the scope and route states automatically. Doing it manually is inflicting a lot of unnecessary pain to self.